# Continuous Alphabetic ToC numbering

Tags: table-of-contents

How do I make the alphabetic numbering continuous? I don't want to change anything else in my ToC. I am pretty sure that this is done from my `jf.sty` package but I'm not good enough to know what to edit in that.

The `.sty` file can be found here: [jf.sty](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.sty).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}                 
\usepackage{bibentry}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}   
\makeatother                    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   
\usepackage{amsthm}                     
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{amssymb}                    
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}             
\usepackage{mathtools}                  
\usepackage{setspace}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}                           
\usepackage{jf}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{1}    
\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\include{Chapters/Introduction}
\include{Chapters/Formula}
\include{Chapters/Evaluation}
\include{Chapters/Discussion}
\include{Chapters/Appendix}
\include{Chapters/References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `jf` is no package file in sense of LaTeX, it is rather something meant to be used as  `\input{jf}`. If you don't need this strange file, omit it. Your document is missing the several files will not produce a filled ToC at all, there is no Appendix as shown in the image and no References section

Comment: ok. Still trying to locate the file which might be controlling the A,B,C and the resetting it for new sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jf` 'package is a mess:

```
\ProvidesPackage{jf}

% Formatting for Journal of Finance papers

% Theorems, etc. (need to load amsthm first)
\newtheoremstyle{jf}% name
{6pt}% Space above
{6pt}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning normal)

\theoremstyle{jf}

% Make References title all caps.
\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}

% Put dots after numbers in section headers.
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{1em}}

% Section and table numbers 
\def\thesection       {\Roman{section}}
\def\thesubsection    {\Alph{subsection}}
\def\thetable         {\Roman{table}}

% Section header format
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}{1}{0mm}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}{2}{0mm}{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\large\itshape}}

% Put section number back in references to subsections and subsubsections.
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection .}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesection .}

% Appendix formatting:

\def\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%         % Start counting sections again
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}% 
% Use uppercase letters for section numbers:
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}% 
% Number equations (A1), etc.:
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}% 
% Put word "Appendix" before appendix number:
  \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{Appendix \csname the##1\endcsname}.\hspace{1em}}
% Same formatting as above, but reset equation counter with each section
  \renewcommand{\section}{\setcounter{equation}{0}\@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
}

\endinput
```

I don't recommend its usage.

Now, to fix the issue with the continous numbers, remove the resetting of `subsection` from `section` counters with `\counterwithout*{subsection}{section}` -- this needs the `chngcntr` package.

Note, that this will cause troubles if there are more than 26 subsections in the total document!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}                 
\usepackage{bibentry}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}   
\makeatother                    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   
\usepackage{amsthm}                     
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{amssymb}                    
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}             
\usepackage{mathtools}                  
\usepackage{setspace}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}                           

\usepackage{chngcntr}



\usepackage{jf}

\counterwithout*{subsection}{section}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\section{Introduction}
\section{Formula}
\subsection{The solution}
\subsection{Comparative}
\section{Evaluation}
\subsection{Foo 1}
\subsection{Foo 2}
\subsection{Foo 3}
\section{Discussion}
\appendix
%\section{Appendix}
%\section{References}

%\include{Chapters/Introduction}
%\include{Chapters/Formula}
%\include{Chapters/Evaluation}
%\include{Chapters/Discussion}
%\include{Chapters/Appendix}
%\include{Chapters/References}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do i do this i didnt quite grasp what i should change in the jf package.  "Now, to fix the issue with the continous numbers, remove the resetting of subsection from section counters with \counterwithout*{subsection}{section} -- this needs the chngcntr package. "? Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: It's shown in the code, after loading the `jf` package, to fix what it screws up

Comment: ok so i can just copy the code and paste it in jf ?

Comment: Just one note: under `% Appendix formatting:`
`% Number equations (A1), etc.:
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}% ` this is not true in my appendix. But i would like it to be true

Comment: solved it by command: `\renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: @user10699: You should not use `jf.sty` at all. It is not well designed, in my point of view

Comment: @user10699 Is this an official journal template you have to use? If so, complain to the journal an ask for advice, it is their job to provide a suiting package, not yours and you shouldn't need to bother.  If you don't want to submit to that journal, bin the package.